# Unitary transformation between two annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Let us say we have the two bosonic annihilation operators $a$ and $b$ with $[a,b^\dagger]=[a,b] =0$. Does a unitary transformation with
\begin{equation} 
a = UbU^\dagger
 \end{equation}
exist? And what is its explicit representation?

Comment: The trivial one $a=b$ with $U=1$

Comment: I edited the question to exclude the case $a=b$

Comment: Bogoliubov transformations are the most general ones that preserve the CCR. Their generator is quadratic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the hermitian operator $X = a^†b +b^†a$. We can see that $[X,a] = -b$ and $[X,b]=-a$, and $[X,a^†] = b^†$ and $[X,b^†]=a^†$. Therefore $U(\theta) = \exp(-iX\theta)$ is a unitary operator that satisfies
$$U(\theta)aU^†(\theta) = a \cos\theta  + ia\sin\theta b$$
$$U(\theta)bU^†(\theta) = ia\sin(\theta)  + b\cos\theta $$
And so if you pick $\theta = \pi/2$ you get
$$U_{\pi/2}a U_{\pi/2}^† = ib$$
$$U_{\pi/2}b U_{\pi/2}^† = ia$$
The extra phase can be removed by another unitary operation that sends $a\mapsto -ia$ and $b\mapsto -ib$. (Hint: this can be implemented via $V=\exp(-i\frac{\pi}{2}(a^†a+b^†b))$)

The action of the complete operation $U = VU_{\pi/2}$ on the states is simple enough to work out. Since $X|0,0\rangle = 0$, we have $U_{\pi/2}|0,0\rangle = |0,0\rangle$, and so
$$U|n,m\rangle = U\frac{(a^†)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\frac{(b^†)^m}{\sqrt{m!}}|0,0\rangle = \frac{(Ua^†U^†)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\frac{(Ub^†U^†)^m}{\sqrt{m!}}|0,0\rangle
=|m,n\rangle$$

For a more general view, note that the four operators
$$X = a^†b + b^†a; \,\, Y = -ia^†b +i b^†a;\,\, Z = a^†a-b^†b;\,\, C = a^†a+b^†b$$
satisfy the commutation relationships of the Lie algebra for $U(2)$. The whole vector space $|n,m\rangle$ can be decomposed into irreducible representations of $U(2)$. Specifically, there's one copy of each irrep $\ell$, each composed of the states that have $n+m = \ell$. You can use the transformation laws of the $\ell$ irreps to work out how the operators act on each state.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly construct such a unitary map by mapping the modes generated by $a$ to the ones generated by $b$ and vice versa. Denote by $|n,m\rangle\propto (a^\dagger)^n(b^\dagger)^m|0\rangle$ the eigenstates of the number operators, then the map $$U:|n,m\rangle\mapsto|m,n\rangle$$ is unitary with $a=U^\dagger bU$ as wished.

Comment: But how would the exponential representation of $U$ look like? $U = \text{exp}(...)$?

Comment: Is there a reason you want it in an exponential representation?

Comment: I need it for a calculation. I already have an idea, but I am not sure if I got it right